# javascript atob gives error for special string

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64

I recently used console for entertaining my self. As I was working with `window.atob()` function which is used to **ENCODE** to base64, I noticed that it gives an error for a special string, `sdfsdfsdf`.
You can try it yourself! Also pay attention this is ENCODING Not decoding as in decoding there may be exist some strings which dont have equal. (My opinion, may not be correct because base64 is unicode)
My question is : **What is the cases of this issue?**

[image]

Comment: you need to use btoa(), not atob(). atob is for un-encoding base64 data into a normal string. unless you can author base64-encoded strings, and hats off if you can, you don't typically feed literal to atob()...

Comment: You didnt get! It does not matter! this function should encode, even previously encoded data can be encoded twice or more!

Comment: i get it, but i'm not sure you do. you can use btoa() to encode it's own result several times, but not atob(), which decodes. it's like how i can multiply any number by any number, but i can't divide by zero.

Comment: @dandavis You're right! I did not check... sorry.

Comment: i get the two mixed up myself sometimes, no biggie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using btoa is the what you are looking for. That one is Decoding not encoding. Also you cannot decode every strings just encoded strings.

Answer (score 1):

Acually atob decodes an encoded base64 to ascii( btoa encodes ), so 'sdfsdfsdf' isn't a valid base64 encoded string. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64.atob